# SQLite - Foreign Keys Contraints - IOs 5

Tags: ios, sqlite, key

it seems that Foreign Keys Constraints are supported since version 3.6.x in SQLite. The version of SQLite on IOS5.0 is 3.7.7 (found in sqlite3.h).

But when I try to insert a row in a table that has a constraint, my row is correctly inserted even if the related foreign key is not existing. I have no error.

Doing the same insert statement using apps like Navicat gives me a "Constraint violation error"

Do you know if foreign keys are supported on IOs 5 ?

Here is the Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE "track" (
     "trackid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     "trackname" TEXT,
     "trackartist" INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT "trackartist" FOREIGN KEY ("trackartist") REFERENCES "artist" ("artistid") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Really simple, isn't it ?

Thanks
Emmanuel

Comment: Can you post the code where you're inserting into the table?

Comment: Hi, I'm using FMDatabase, the code is really simple :   [db executeUpdate:@"insert into track (trackname,trackartist) values (?,?)" ,
         @"new track",
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:i]]

Comment: Weird...I have the exact same scenario as you... (Navicat, iOS, FMDB). Same issue. Gotta love SO.

Answer (score 13):

Foreign keys are disabled by default. You have to enable them separately for each connection. The setting isn't "sticky". You have to do this every time you connect to a SQLite database.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Odds are good that Navicat takes care of that for you. In your own code, it's your job.

Comment: That's great but how do i do this ? Do I just execute this to the DB? How do I use this `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` line of code ?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, you execute that as if it were a SQL statement. [Details on SQLite's C interface](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html)

Answer (score 4):

I've finally found the solution .... and catcall you were right.

By default the sqlite database is opened with foreign keys option disabled, even if the tables have been built with foreign keys constraints !

So just make this simple request :

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
```

just after opening the database, and outside a transaction (if you are using fmdatabase and transactions functionality)

Hope this will help somebody else.

Emmanuel

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it using `FMDB`:

```
[database executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is on the doc:
[SQLite Doc](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

and when you open the connection:

```
[database executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"];
```