# Swift with FMDB DELETE ignoring foreign key constraints. XCode 12.5

Tags: swift, swiftui, fmdb

I have been trying to solve this problem for some time now.  I'm writing an application using Swift/SwiftUI and FMDB over SQlite3.  When a delete is executed on a table where there are existing foreign keys I expect the delete to fail.  It doesn't and there is no error thrown.

In XCode I'm linking with libsqlite3.tbd listed as date modified 03/16/2021.  Inside the tbd file I find:
install-name:    '/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib'
current-version: 321.3
compatibility-version: 9

I find the libsqlite3.dylib in:
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
Info shows it was created 04/09/2021.  No apparent version

What is happening is that I have foreign keys on a table named BudgetedExpense to a table named BudgetDescription.

```
BudgetDescription DDL
CREATE TABLE budget_description (
    id                  INTEGER     DEFAULT (0) 
                                    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                                    UNIQUE,
    income_expense_code INTEGER (8) NOT NULL
                                    DEFAULT (0),
    description         STRING      NOT NULL
                                    DEFAULT (0),
    income_or_expense   INTEGER     NOT NULL
                                    DEFAULT (0) 
);

BudgetedExpense DDL

CREATE TABLE budgeted_expense (
    expense_id         INTEGER         NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0) 
                                       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                                       UNIQUE,
    account_code       INTEGER (8)     NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    expense_code       INTEGER (8)     NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    budget_year        INTEGER (4)     NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    budget_month       INTEGER (2)     NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    expense_budget     DECIMAL (12, 2) NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    expense_spent      DECIMAL (12, 2) NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    unexpected_expense DECIMAL (12, 2) NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    category_code      INTEGER (8)     NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    hidden             BOOLEAN         NOT NULL
                                       DEFAULT (0),
    hidden_id          INTEGER         DEFAULT (0),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        account_code,
        budget_year,
        budget_month
    )
    REFERENCES budget (account_code,
    budget_year,
    budget_month),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        expense_code
    )
    REFERENCES budget_description (income_expense_code) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        category_code
    )
    REFERENCES categories (category_code) 
);
```

My FMDB code that executes the database updates is:

```
    func updateDatabaseTable(query: String)-> Bool
    {
        var updateSuccessful: Bool = false
        
        let pragmaQuery = "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;"
        
        if openDatabase() {
            do {
            try database.executeUpdate(pragmaQuery, values: nil)
            } catch {
                
            }
            
            queue.inTransaction() {
                database, rollback in
                do {
                    
                    try database.executeUpdate(query, values: nil)
                    updateSuccessful = true
                    
                    if showQuerys && updateSuccessful {
                        print("Update query is:\n \(query)")
                    }
                    
                }
                catch {
                    rollback.initialize(to: true)
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    print(database.lastError())
                    print(database.lastErrorMessage())
                    print("UPDATE QUERY FAILED")
                    print(query)
                    updateSuccessful = false
                }
            }
            _ = closeDatabase()
        }

        return updateSuccessful

    }
```

The SQL that executes to delete a row in the BudgetDescription table is:

```
    // Delete a specific record for a given income/expense code.
    func deleteBudgetDescriptionRecordSQL(forIncomeExpenseCode incomeExpenseCode: Int) -> String
    {
        let query =
        """
        DELETE FROM \(budget_description_table)
            WHERE \(income_expense_code_field) = \(incomeExpenseCode)
        """
        return query
    }
```

The function I've written is:

```
    // **** DELETE BUDGET DESCRIPTION RECORD FOR A GIVEN ACCOUNT CODE **** //
    func deleteBudgetDescriptionRecord(forIncomeExpenseCode incomeExpenseCode: Int) -> Bool
    {
        var updateResult: Bool
        updateResult = updateBudgetDescriptions(updateQuery: deleteBudgetDescriptionRecordSQL(forIncomeExpenseCode: incomeExpenseCode))
        
        if showQuerys {
            print("\nQUERY: deleteBudgetDescriptionRecordSQL(forIncomeExpenseCode: incomeExpenseCode)")
            print(deleteBudgetDescriptionRecordSQL(forIncomeExpenseCode: incomeExpenseCode))
        }
        
        if updateResult == false {
            print("deleteBudgetDescriptionRecordSQL returned FALSE when executing QUERY:")
            print(deleteBudgetDescriptionRecordSQL(forIncomeExpenseCode: incomeExpenseCode))
            return updateResult
        }
        
        return updateResult
    }
```

Which executes:

```
    // **********************  PRIVATE DRIVER FUNCTIONS TO EXECUTE DBMANAGER UPDATE DATABASE TABLE METHOD ***********//
    
    private func updateBudgetDescriptions(updateQuery: String) -> Bool
    {
        var updateResult: Bool
        updateResult = DBManager.shared.updateDatabaseTable(query: updateQuery)
        return updateResult
    }
```

When I execute this DELETE sql in a utility program I have called SQLiteStudio, it fails with a foreign_key notice.  But when executed on the same database with FMDB it executes without error or any logging notice.

I'm relying to an extent on the database integrity to throw errors if there is a foreign key when a delete occurs.  I've worked for days on this.

I have an XCode project that will demonstrate this but don't know where or how to upload it for someone to examine though.

I'd appreciate any thoughts that might help me get the constraints to work.

Bob

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745850/sqlite-foreign-keys-contraints-ios-5) could help

Comment: Thank you for that suggested link.  But the solution to implement PRAGMA foreign_key=on; is already in my code.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but it is a little odd that the foreign key is linked to an ordinary column and not the primary key of the other table but maybe there is a reason for this.

Comment: Well that is a thought, I'll play around with that.  Still the constraint is honored in SQLiteStudio. Just not in the app with FMDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after quite a few tests I've discovered what I need to do to be able to have the DELETE throw the "Foreign Key Constraint" error.  There are three things I needed to do.  1). I need the PRAGMA statement as a part of the DELETE query like this:

```
        PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;
        DELETE FROM \(budget_description_table)
            WHERE \(income_expense_code_field) = \(incomeExpenseCode);
```

2. Then I needed to change the call to database.executeUpdate to database.executeStatements to execute the sequence of two statments...

```
    // EXECUTE A SERIES OF SQL STATEMENTS
    func executeSQLStatements(query: String)-> Bool
    {
            //        let time1 = Date()
        if openDatabase() {
//            queue.inTransaction() {
//                database, rollback in
                if !database.executeStatements(query) {
//                    rollback.initialize(to: true)
                    print("Failed to execute the query \(query)")
                    print(database.lastError())
                    print(database.lastErrorMessage())
                    if database.lastErrorMessage()=="FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" {
                        print("You can't do dat")
                    }
                } else {
                    if showQuerys
                    {
                        print("IN executeSQLStatements - Successfully executed the query \(query)")
                    }
                }
//            }
          _ = closeDatabase()
        }
        return true
    }
```

3. BUT FINALLY and this is the clincher.... I needed to eliminate the use of the FMDatabaseQueue.  When the transactions are put through the queue for some reason the constraints aren't adhered to... When I use the function as above with the queue commented out I get:

//***********

2021-05-22 14:31:57.089895-0400 SqliteTest[2400:219563] Error inserting batch: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Failed to execute the query PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS = ON;
DELETE FROM budget_description
WHERE income_expense_code = 20010
Error Domain=FMDatabase Code=19 "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=FOREIGN KEY constraint failed}
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

//***********

I tried a number of combinations of how to use the PRAGMA statement with the DELETE statement and this combination is the only one that worked.  And it only worked in combination without using the FMDatabaseQueue.

When used with the database.executeUpdate even without the FMDatabaseQueue only one statement processed and the row wasn't deleted, but that is because only the PRAGMA statement was executed.  There was no error thrown, as the DELETE wasn't executed.

When used with database.executeStatements with the FMDatabaseQueue the row was deleted and no error was thrown...

So 1) Use the PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON; with the DELETE 2) Use executeStatements 3) DON'T use FMDatabaseQueue.

Regards,
Bob